# Helvetica font and ohm symbol

Tags: fonts, units

I am writing an industrial laboratory report, where I need to use Helvetica.
My preamble contains:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{phv}\selectfont
\usepackage[margin=10pt, font=bf, ]{caption}
```

I need the ohm symbol in the text of the document and in numerous captions, that are in bold characters. I have tried a lot of options, such as `\usepackage{textcomp}`, `\usepackage[squaren, Gray, cdot]{SIunits}`, `\usepackage{gensymb}`, and many ways to write the ohm or Omega symbol. However none looked really  nice. I am currently using `$\Omega$` in the main text, and `$\boldsymbol\Omega$` in the captions. Is there any way to get an Omega matching visually Helvetica text?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks) (you can also highlight the code and click the "code" button - the one with "{}" on it). You can also use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit. `:)`

Comment: @Yves Is using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX a possibility? Finding a good symbol is tricky, and it's a lot easier if you can load UTF-8 font symbol.

Comment: I assume you've already verified that `Helvetica` supplies a glyph capital-Omega, right? If there's no such glyph, it might be very difficult to find one that matches Helvetica's rather distinctive look...

Answer (score 9):

Finding the correct symbol is tricky. Rather than loading `phv` directly, or using the `helvet` package, I'd be tempted to use the newer `tgheros` package. This uses [TeX Gyre](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/) Heros (another Helvetica clone, but with better glyph coverage). Loading this along with `textcomp` will set up `\textohm` properly. You could then use that directly, but I'd (unsurprisingly) favour using my own [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package to deal properly with units and so forth:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tgheros,textcomp}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=bf]{caption}
\sisetup{detect-weight}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}

Some text \textohm{}  \si{\ohm}.
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Some text  \textohm{} \si{\ohm}.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this option. I should have indicated  that I am a beginner in Latex, as I am trying  to evaluate the feasibility of using it for industrial documents, as a pilot experiment. Arial font was the font previously used for the laroratory reports, and I picked up Helvetica as a reasonnably close option, in order to maintain visual consistency with prior art....

Comment: I have tried and it looks magnificent. I am anxious to convert all other SI units. I do have in this pilot report Nm, MPa, GHz, degrees Celcius, Volts, etc. These were obviously less critical visually, but of course using the real unit is far more satisfactory