# Asymmetric uncertainties with siunitx package

Tags: siunitx

Is it possible to typeset asymmetric uncertainties, e.g. `$0.84_{-0.01}^{+0.02}$` with the [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package?

Comment: I don't think you can (but I'm not sure). There is an idea on [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43415/asymmetrical-tolerancing).

Comment: I would, as @SvendTveskæg suggested, write a wrapper macro for that. Do you also need that for tables (i.e. the `S` column)? How should the output look like when the two uncertainties have a different width (e.g. `-0.01` and `+0.005`)?

Comment: Currently the answer is 'no': I still don't understand the concept of an asymmetric uncertainty! That's of course not going to stop me trying to add it if I can find an interface, but I currently don't have one that I feel works.

Comment: @Joseph: Imagine you are measuring very low temperatures, for example at 1.3K. Now you measures are distributed which results in the uncertainty around the mean value of 1.3K. But this distribution is asymetric: You can have measures 2K above your mean value at 3.3K. But you can't have measures 2K below your mean value at -0.7K. Of course you can calculate a (symmetric) standard deviation and use that to calculate a symmetric uncertainty. But that doesn't reflect the "true" uncertainty well, because you have less uncertainty below than above the mean value due to the asymetric distribution.

Comment: With `parse-numbers=false` it works, but that's probably not, what you want.

Comment: In draws the tolerances are often assymetric

Comment: I've duped to a similar question, as otherwise I'll be repeating the same answer. I hope that's OK.